# Xamarin.Forms Same Page Navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for the best way to change the content of a page, without navigating to a new one.
I tried having two stacklayouts, and on a button press I'd change the IsVisible and IsEnabled properties of each stack layout. Although this worked, I was left with a small white gap at the end of each layout (I believe this is a Xamarin.Forms bug).

What would be the best way to accomplish this task? Is there anything built into Xamarin.Forms that can do this that I have missed?

Here is a little sketch design for you to see what I mean:
[image: content 1]
[image: content 2]

Before suggesting I use tabs, I'll add that I already have tabs in the application, the sketch doesn't show that though. I need this navigation to work on only ONE page.

The code I used before, that didn't work is:
(Before anybody mentions the poor naming conventions and lack of content, I had to strip it all out as it's code written for an employer.

C#:

```
private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Content2.IsVisible = false;
    Content2.IsEnabled = false;
    Content1.IsVisible = true;
    Content1.IsEnabled = true;
}

private void Button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Content2.IsVisible = true;
    Content2.IsEnabled = true;
    Content1.IsEnabled = false;
    Content1.IsVisible = false;
}
```

XML:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="content1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2">
<StackLayout Spacing="0">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="20,20,20,20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="text:" FontFamily="{StaticResource BoldFont}"/>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image x:Name="content1image" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25"/>
                <Label x:Name="content1label" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font}" FontSize="27" TextColor="#969696"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Entry x:Name="content1Entry" Keyboard="Numeric" Margin="0,25,0,0" Placeholder="0.00000000" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font}" FontSize="27" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#969696"/>
            <Label x:Name="content1Label2" FontSize="14" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#969696"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout Padding="20,30,20,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="content1Label3" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font}"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="content1button" Image="image.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25"/>
            <Entry x:Name="content1Entry2" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font}" FontSize="12" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0,-1,0,0">
        <Label x:Name="content1Label4" FontSize="19" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font}"/>
        <Label x:Name="content1Label5" FontSize="12" TextColor="#b6b6b6" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font}"/>

        <Button x:Name="content1Button2" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderRadius="25" BackgroundColor="#2r432d" BorderColor="#2r432d" TextColor="White" FontFamily="{StaticResource Font}" FontSize="20" BorderWidth="3" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
    </StackLayout>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Your solution is the best one. The bug you are referring, its probably not xamarin forms. You are not most likely giving the correct spaceto your views, that's why they are not occupying the full page. Without any code, it's difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have added the previous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had very much success using Stacklayouts. Grids however has a lot of customizability and in my case it expands to fill all the area that you wish for.

This is how I would do it.

**Xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" IsVisible="False" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Grid1 Label"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="375" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Button x:Name="btnGrid1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<Grid x:Name="Grid2" IsVisible="False" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Grid2 Label"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="375" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Button x:Name="btnGrid2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind**

```
private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Grid2.IsVisible = false;
    Grid1.IsVisible = true;
}

private void Button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Grid2.IsVisible = true;
    Grid1.IsVisible = false;
}
```